# Aligning Images side-by-side with columns in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4, and trying to align my columns so that I have 2 images next to each-other on medium or larger viewports, but they keep aligning themselves one on top of the other.

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <img class="img-fluid"
                                src="img/1.PNG">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-5 d-none d-md-block">
                            <img class="img-fluid"
                                src="img/2.PNG">
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

[Image of code and example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuBB8.png)

Answer (score 0):

That should work just fine if you take all the extra bits from the Row classes and just have *class="row"* Your column widths are both set to *5* though, *6* would be ideal for centering.

To assist with sleeker code, on the *img* classes try removing it all except for *img-fluid*

Comment: hmm.  Unfortunately, it is not working.   Even when I remove it from the entire page into a test html page, it is still one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your column classes are wrong. `col` fills all available space, and `col-5` takes 5 columns on all screens. And in this case your `col-5` is overriding your `col` anyway. What you actually need to do:

- Use `col-md-6` on both the images in place of `col col-5`. Your images will align themselves side by side from medium and up.

Also, you do NOT need to add `d-none d-md-block` to the parent and all the child classes. If you don't want to show a particular div in less than md, using it on the parent is enough.

Answer (score 0):

For demonstration purposes I went ahead and used a dummy image that I could get to work. Your structure should be as follows.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">   
   </div>
   <div class="col-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
   </div>
</div>
```

Using the different **Large, Medium, and Small** bootstrap classes allows for your row to adjust on different screen sizes, while maintaining that row structure. This link [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) is also very helpful for learning the system.